# want to show releases till date in rallyreleasecombobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I am using `rallyreleasecombobox` to display releases in combobox, and I am able to show the combobox with all releases but I want to remove future releases from the combobox. Just want to show releases which are still running or completed.
Below is my some of the code  I wrote

Please any suggestions on this, thanks in advance

```
                this.down('#SevFilter').add({
                    xtype: 'rallyreleasecombobox',
                    //multiSelect: true,
                    itemId: 'priorityComboBox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Release Start:',
                    model: 'release',
                    width: 400,
                    valueField: 'ReleaseStartDate',
                    displayField: 'Name',
                    //  multiSelect: true,
                    //field: 'Name',
                    _removeFunction: function(){
                        console.log("this.store");
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        //select: this._onSelect,
                        select: this._onFirstReleaseSelect,
                        scope: this
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example removes future releases by adding a filter to the release combobox

```
var today = new Date();
var filters = [
    {
       property : 'ReleaseStartDate',
       operator : '<=',
       value : today
     }
];


var rComboBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ReleaseComboBox',{ 
    listeners:{
         ready: function(combobox){
             var rRef = combobox.getRecord().get('_ref'); 
             this._getData(rRef);
         },
         select: function(combobox){
              var rRef = combobox.getRecord().get('_ref'); 
              this._getData(rRef);
         },
         scope: this 
      }
  });
  rComboBox.store.filter(filters);
  this.add(rComboBox);
```

The source code is [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/remove-future-releases-from-combobox).